# Chrome tabs keep crashing

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, crash

Lately my Chrome tabs on Windows 10 became really unstable. Especially on Youtube and Myanimelist. The tabs just crash at random, sometimes I have a page open for 5 mins and then they just stop working.
Does anyone have a fix for this issue?

Comment: Try updating it and disabling extensions. When problem is resolved enable them one by one to trace the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple things:

Update Chrome - Go to settings, and select About in the left hand column.  It should automatically update after selecting About.  The current version is 51.0.2704.106 m

If that doesn't help, try to Uninstall and Reinstall Chrome.